# When in C++14 with RVO/NRVO closed, how is the object returned?

Tags: c++, c++14, return-value-optimization, nrvo

I am learning about move semantics, so I wrote a small program as follows to practice:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int one_int = 123;

class A {
public:
    int *a;

    A(int *ptr) : a(ptr) {
        cout << "In A's constructor..." << endl;
    }

    A(const A &other) {
        cout << "In A's copy constructor..." << endl;
        a = other.a;
    }

    A(A &&other) noexcept {
        cout << "In A's move constructor..." << endl;
        a = other.a;
        other.a = nullptr;
    }

    ~A() {
        cout << "In A's destructor..." << endl;
    }
};

A make_obj() {
    cout << "In make_obj..." << endl;
    return A(&one_int);
}

A make_obj_by_move(A &&source) {
    cout << "In make_obj_by_move..." << endl;
    return A(static_cast<A&&>(source));
}

A make_obj_by_copy(A source) {
    cout << "In make_obj_by_copy..." << endl;
    return A(source);
}

int main() {
    A obj2 = make_obj_by_move(make_obj());
    cout << endl;
    A obj1 = make_obj_by_copy(make_obj());
    cout << endl;
    // to ensure that the information printed when obj1 and obj2 are destroyed is separated from the above ones
    obj1.a = nullptr;
    obj2.a = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

I turned off RVO/NRVO of clang by the `-fno-elide-constructors` compiler option and use `-std=c++14`. I got the following output, very confusing:

```
In make_obj...                                
In A's constructor...                   // make tmp obj
In A's move constructor...              // w/o RVO, need another construction to get return value?
In A's destructor...                    // destory the temp obj in make_obj scope?                
In make_obj_by_move...                
In A's move constructor...              // call the move constructor like expected? I guess by the position of "copy constructor" below
In A's move constructor...              // what happened here ???
In A's destructor...                    // destory which?            
In A's move constructor...              // w/o NRVO, need another construction to get obj1?
In A's destructor...                    // destory which?
In A's destructor...                    // destory which?

In make_obj...                            
In A's constructor...                   // make tmp obj
In A's move constructor...              // w/o RVO, need another construction to get return value?
In A's destructor...                    // destory the temp obj in make_obj scope?            
In A's move constructor...              // what happened here ???
In make_obj_by_copy...                
In A's copy constructor...              // call the copy constructor like expected
In A's move constructor...              // what happened here ???
In A's destructor...                    // destory which?            
In A's move constructor...              // w/o NRVO, need another construction to get obj2?
In A's destructor...                    // destory which?
In A's destructor...                    // destory which?
In A's destructor...                    // destory which?            

In A's destructor...                    // destory obj1/obj2
In A's destructor...                    // destory obj2/obj1
```

What exactly happened here? Why have many unexpected move constructions and destructions been called? I tried to explain some of the output, but there are still many lines of output that I don't understand. Can you help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Try printing `this` in your constructors and destructors so you have an easier time matching up which destructors correspond to which constructors.

Comment: `// destory which?` -- As mentioned, you know which object is being destroyed by printing `this`.  In general, you should always print `this` in the constructors and destructors, so that you are not confused as to what is being created and destroyed.  Right now, outputing `this` is the only way any of us can see what's really going on in a speedy manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of any copy elision, there are usually three objects involved in returning from a function:

1. The object you pass to the `return` keyword
2. The function's return value
3. The object that gets initialized by the return value

- The object you give to the `return` keyword is (often) a function-local object and storage for it lives within the function's stack frame.
- The function's return value exists outside the function's scope, within the caller's stack frame as a temporary object that exists only until the end of the full-expression in which the function was called.
- The object that gets initialized by the return value also exists in the caller's stack frame and (usually) has a name and some wider scope within the caller

Copy elision lets the compiler collapse all three of those objects into one in the correct circumstances.

---

I've annotated your program's output to show exactly which objects each line is talking about:

```
In make_obj...                                
In A's constructor...         // create function-local temporary object
In A's move constructor...    // construct make_obj's return value by move from the function local temp object
In A's destructor...          // destroy the function-local temp object
In make_obj_by_move...
In A's move constructor...    // create function-local temporary object
In A's move constructor...    // construct make_obj_by_move's return value by move from the function-local temp object
In A's destructor...          // destroy the function-local temp object
In A's move constructor...    // construct obj1 in main by move from make_obj_by_move's return object
In A's destructor...          // destroy make_obj_by_move's return object
In A's destructor...          // destroy make_obj's return object

In make_obj...
In A's constructor...         // create function-local temporary object
In A's move constructor...    // construct make_obj's return value by move from the function local temp object
In A's destructor...          // destroy the function-local temp object
In A's move constructor...    // construct make_obj_by_copy's source parameter by move from make_obj's return object
In make_obj_by_copy...                
In A's copy constructor...    // create function-local temp object by copy from the source parameter
In A's move constructor...    // construct make_obj_by_copy's return value by move from the function-local temp object
In A's destructor...          // destroy the function-local temp object
In A's move constructor...    // construct obj2 in main by move from make_obj_by_move's return object
In A's destructor...          // destroy make_obj_by_copy's return object
In A's destructor...          // destroy make_obj_by_copy's source parameter
In A's destructor...          // destroy make_obj's return object

In A's destructor...          // destroy obj2
In A's destructor...          // destroy obj1
```

---

As a side-note, in these sorts of situations it can be useful to print the value of the `this` pointer in each of your instrumented operations so that you can easily see exactly which object the operation was performed on.